# How to check if user is logged in after OnBoarding React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am struggling to figure out a way to check if a is logged-in after the first launch of the app and then sending them to the MainStack which contains every screen after the AuthStack. I'm using FireBase for auth.

My Auth stack contains my signin, signup, and forgot password screen:

```
export default function AuthStack() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Login"
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

This is my Main Stack, which is a drawer navigator:

```
export default function MainStack() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
            drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
            initialRouteName="Home"
            screenOptions={{
                drawerActiveBackgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
                drawerActiveTintColor: '#fff',
                drawerInactiveTintColor: '#333',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                headerTintColor: '#00BFFF',
                drawerLabelStyle: {
                    marginLeft: -25,
                    fontSize: 15
                },
            }}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{
                drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="home-outline" size={22} color={color} />
                )
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Calendar' component={CalendarScreen} options={{
                drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="calendar-outline" size={22} color={color} />
                )
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Chat' component={ChatScreen} options={{
                drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="call-outline" size={22} color={color} />
                )
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Goals' component={GoalsScreen} options={{
                drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="checkmark-circle-outline" size={22} color={color} />
                )
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Journal' component={JournalScreen} options={{
                drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="journal-outline" size={22} color={color} />
                )
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Resources' component={ResourcesScreen} options={{
                drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="search-outline" size={22} color={color} />
                )
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='User Profile' component={UserProfileScreen} options={{
                drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="person-outline" size={22} color={color} />
                )
            }} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Lastly, here lies the issue. These are my routes, but I can't figure out how to send the user to the MainStack after they initially login. The last statement works perfectly fine, but the error is in the 'else if', I can't seem to incorporate authenticating the user and verifying if it's the first app launch at the same time.

```
export default function Routes() {
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
    const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = useState(null);
    function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
        setUser(user);
        if (initializing) {
            setInitializing(false);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = auth.onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
        return subscriber;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then(value => {
            if (value === null) {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true');
                setIsFirstLaunch(true); 
            }
            else {
                setIsFirstLaunch(false);
            }
        })
    }, []);

    if (isFirstLaunch === null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (isFirstLaunch === true) {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{
                        headerShown: false
                    }}>
                    <Stack.Screen name='OnBoarding' component={OnBoardingScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
    else {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                {user ? <MainStack /> : <AuthStack />}
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
```

Below is AuthProvider with firebase

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

import { auth } from '../firebase/firebase';

export const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                user,
                setUser,
                login: async (email, password) => {
                    try {
                        await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                },
                register: async (email, password) => {
                    try {
                        await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                },
                logout: async () => {
                    try {
                        await auth.signOut();
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at react-native but what I think in this case is that you need to add MainStack as Stack.Screen in AuthStack, so when you change route you would be moving to MainStack

sth like this :

```
    export default function AuthStack() {
        return (
            <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Login"
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false
                }}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainStack} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        );
    }
```

and in login button :

```
<Button
        title="Login"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Main')}
      />
```

Comment: It does the same issue. On the other hand, it displays the On Boarding screen only once like intended. On the other hand, after clicking on the login button, it doesn't do anything. But, when I close the application and open it once again, i'll be redirected to the Home Screen.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you have to check whether it's the first launch can be modified. You can display a splash screen on your app until you fetch the required info to check whether there is a logged in user and then hide the splash screen. And based on whether there is a user or not, you can load different navigators from your `App.js` file.

Here's what that might look like if you're using Expo with React Native:

```js
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [appReady, setAppReady] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        // Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

        // Make any API calls you need to do here
        const user = await authStorage.getUser();
        if (!user) return;

        setUser(user);
      } catch (e) {
        logger.log(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppReady(true);
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    }
    prepare();
  }, []);

  if (!appReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        {user ? <MainStack /> : <AuthStack />}
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

When you need to log the user out, simply set the user to `null`. You're probably going to want to set this state from another component inside one of your screens. And to be able to manipulate the user state in the `App.js` file from a child component without [prop drilling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-prop-drilling-and-how-to-avoid-it/), we can use the `useContext` hook. So your code can look something like this:

```js
// context.js

import React from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export default AuthContext;
```

```js
// App.js

import AuthContext from "./context";
...

const [user, setUser] = useState();

...

<AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {user ? <FeedNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
      </NavigationContainer>
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

And in a child component, you can access this state and set the user to `null` when the click on the logout button:

```js
// child.js

import { useContext } from "react";

import AuthContext from "./context";

export default Child = () => {
  const { setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    // Log user out using firebase fn
  };

  return(
    <Button onPress={handleLogout}>
        Logout
    </Button>
  )
};
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll give this a try as well. Wouldn't a splash screen defeat the purpose of having an onboarding swiper/screen to display only on the original download of the application?

Comment: AFAIK it's completely okay to use splash screens even on first installs, because more often than not, it's not only the auth state you're checking, you might be loading fonts, images etc. So you want all of that to happen before the user can interact with your app. If you observe, most apps you download for this first time will still show a splash screen. This is because they're probably also making a call to the local store to check if onboarding is complete. If there's no state set, they'll show the onboarding screens

Comment: Ok, i'll give this a shot. also, I updated the question and added my AuthProvider file. So instead of an OnBoarding screen, I could simply have a Splash Screen while everything loads in if I understand correctly

Comment: I've also updated my Routes.js page by adding the function I previously had to set the user. It's in the third code block.

Comment: Yup, everything looks good! Just use the user state to display either the MainStack or the AuthStack and you should have no issues

Comment: Is there a way to do that within the Navigation Container in the else-if statement?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: In my else-statement, it will check if the user is logged in within the NavigationContainer and then send them to the correct stack -- either the MainStack or the AuthStack. What I am trying to explain is that, is there a way to do that in my else-if statement when I check if isFirstLaunch.

Comment: @SudhanvaM Hi, when i implemented your solution after teh splash screen loads i see the <AuthStack /> for a a couple of seconds then it automatically navigates to the <MainStack />. How do i keep the splash visible until it shows the <MainStack /> straight away if user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Simply maintain a async storage.
if user successfully login set async storage TRUE & if user logout async storage false. based on the condtions, we can maintain a user login/logout.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that, please? How would I be able to incorporate that within the existing code? would there be a way to check if the user is logged-in within the first Navigation Container? In the "else-if" statement. Similar to what I already have within the else statement